# Looping over name/value pairs of an optional dictionary

Tags: swift

I'm still *wrapping* my brain around the use of optionals in Swift, and am curious how to best handle looping over name/value pairs of an optional dictionary parameter. Consider:

```
func printNamesAndValues(of foo: [String: String]?=nil) -> Void {
    for (name, value) in foo {
        print("\(name) is \(value)")
    }
}

printNamesAndValues()
printNamesAndValues(of: nil)
printNamesAndValues(of: ["a": "b"])
```

The Swift 3 compiler errors on the `for` loop line, reporting:

> Value of optional type [String: String]?" not unwrapped; Did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

In this situation, it seems like force unwrapping is the wrong approach, since `foo` could be nil by way of the default parameter or the caller passing nil. So, should I use a `guard` before the `for` loop? Or wrap the for loop with `if foo != nil { ... }`? Or is there another preferred method I'm overlooking?

Comment: On a side note, `if foo != nil` is almost never appropriate. It requires you then use `foo!` whenever you wish to use `foo`. Use it only if you want to check if `foo` is `nil`, but don't actually need to use `foo`. Otherwise, use `if let foo = foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally up to you. There are several ways how to do it

```
guard let dict = foo else { return }
// use dict

if let dict = foo {
    // use dict
}

if foo != nil {
    // use foo! - not recommended actually
}
```

I'd prefer `guard` if the dictionary is needed for the execution of this method (but this could be avoided by making the foo parameter not-optional).

In case of this exact method, I would prefer to modify the declaration as

```
func printNamesAndValues(of foo: [String: String] = [:]) -> Void {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach varies with your intent. The reason the compiler complains about optionals is because there's no best way to handle them, so it's up to you as a programmer to decide what to do. That's why the compiler can't just deal with them on its own.

In your case, you have to unwrap `foo` prior to using it on the right side of a for loop. Remember that `[String: String]` (a.k.a. `Dictionary<String, String`) is a sequence, but `[String: String]?` (a.k.a. `Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>`) is not.

As you said, there are two main ways of handling this.

1. ### Using `guard let`

   ```
    func printNamesAndValues(of foo: [String: String]? = nil) -> Void {
       guard let foo = foo else { return }
       for (name, value) in foo {
           print("\(name) is \(value)")
       }
   }
   ```

   This is the more extreme of the two options, because it forces you to break the scope (the current function) if `foo` is `nil`, which is very likely not something you want to do, seeing as `nil` is the default value, and likely a perfectly (logically speaking) viable value.
2. ### Using `if let`

   ```
   func printNamesAndValues(of foo: [String: String]? = nil) -> Void {
       if let foo = foo else {
           for (name, value) in foo {
               print("\(name) is \(value)")
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This approach will skip the loop if `foo` is `nil`, but the rest of the method would carry on.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to work with Optionals where you need non-Opional value, there are several ways:

- Use forced unwrapping (`!`)

  Do this only when you are 100% sure that the Optional cannot be nil. Your case, of course does not match.
- Use optional chaining (`?.`)

  Only valid when you want to use some methods. In many cases you need to combine other solutions. Eendje's answer is a good example.
- Use optional binding (`if-let` or `guard-let`)

  You already have several answers describing this.
- Supply default value using nil-coalescing operator (`??`)

  You can write something like this:

  ```
  func printNamesAndValues(of foo: [String: String]?=nil) -> Void {
      for (name, value) in foo ?? [:] {
          print("\(name) is \(value)")
      }
  }
  ```

  `[:]` is an empty Dictionary, and when the left hand side of `??` (in the code above, `foo`) is nil, the right hand side (`[:]`) is evaluated and becomes the result of the operation. For an empty Dictionary, `for-in` does not execute the loop body.

Seems the third and the fourth both fit for your case. Please try.

Comment: Why would optional chaining not be useful in his case? `foo?.forEach { ... }` would do just fine no? (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in an `if let` to find out if it's nil before looping.

```
func printNamesAndValues(of foo: [String: String]?=nil) -> Void {
    if let f = foo {
       for (name, value) in f {
           print("\(name) is \(value)")
       }
    }
}

printNamesAndValues()
printNamesAndValues(of: nil)
printNamesAndValues(of: ["a": "b"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using optional chaining would suffice in your case.

```
func printNamesAndValues(of foo: [String: String]? = nil) -> Void {
    foo?.forEach { print("\($0.0) is \($0.1)") }
}

printNamesAndValues()                 // nothing happens
printNamesAndValues(of: nil)          // nothing happens
printNamesAndValues(of: ["a": "b"])   // prints: "a is b"
```